# how to save a file at the server in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a log file which needs to be written to the server . If i had the code in a code behind file for a web form i would have done this

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("/ErrorLogFile/ErrorLogFile.log"),json);
```

Now, since my code sits inside the App_Code folder i have no access to the Server class ...so i have to tell it to go find the folder and then write it to the disk. I can accomplish this by telling it the full path and it will work . but i want to tell it to go look for the ErrorLogFolder in the directory you are in and then write the file there . Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Web namespace, [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) exposes the same functionality from your "code" files.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("STRING VALUE");
```

Comment: my bad , i use the same concept a zillion times through my application  just to get the session , didn't look for the server in the context ..

Answer (score 1):

If your using the App_Code resources from your code-behind, just pass the path to the function in your App_Code

```
appCodeClass.callFunc(Server.MapPath("/ErrorLogFile/ErrorLogFile.log"), arg2, arg3, ..);
```